# For an odd prime $p$, following curve has a non-trivial solution

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $F(x,y)$ be a binary cubic form such that $F(x,y) \equiv a(x-by)(x-cy)(x-dy) \hspace{1mm} (\text{mod } p)$. Then the curve $z^{3} = F(x,y)$ has a non-zero solution in the $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$, the space of $p$-adic numbers.

When $p \equiv 2 \hspace{1mm} (\text{mod } 3)$, the result follows because every residue class is a cubic-residue. Then I can lift the solution using Hensel's lemma. I am struggling to see it when $p \equiv 1 \hspace{1mm} (\text{mod} 3)$.

I know of a slightly high-level proof :The curve $z^{3} = F(x,y)$ is smooth over primes $p \equiv 1 \hspace{1mm} (\text{mod } 3)$ and has genus $\binom{3-1}{2} = 1$. Therefore, using the Hasse-bound I could surmise that if $N$ is the number of points on the projective curve then

$$-2\sqrt{p} \leq N - (p+1) \leq 2\sqrt{p} $$ which gives that $$1 \le p - 2\sqrt{p} + 1 \leq N \leq p + 2\sqrt{p} + 1.$$

I am interested in knowing an elementary proof, as compared to what I have put up for $p \equiv 1 \hspace{1mm} (\text{mod } 3)$. Also what can I do for $p = 3$?

Comment: There's probably a character-sum proof, but the character-sum estimates mostly come from Hasse bounds to begin with....

Comment: What can I do about $p = 3$? I forgot to mention that earlier...

Comment: Your "higher level proof" is wrong as written - the Hasse bound only holds for elliptic curves... that is, you must first assert that your curve has an $\mathbb{F}_p$-point (as well as having genus 1) which is a small techncical detail often missed!! Although, fortunately over $\mathbb{F}_p$ all genus 1 curves have a point see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4077812/801393) so the arguement is salvagable with extra work.

Comment: @Mummytheturkey Thanks.. I swept those extra details under the carpet. Sadly your answer in the link does not evade the technicalities either.. You have any idea about $p = 3$?

Comment: For $p=3$ you can put your curve in Weierstrass form $ZY^2=X^3+AX^2Z+BXZ^2+CZ^3$ so that Hensel lemma works.

Comment: Actually I have been working out this a little bit -- hence I have a related question. Say that $F(x,y)$ was irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. Is it true that $Z^{3} = F(X,Y)$ has a solution $(x,y,z)$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$ with $z \neq 0$?